# Extracting more than 100 links from tickertape.in using asyncio makes it run forever

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to extract data from tickertape.in (just the % change of the price) but when I have more than 100 links it is running forever.

here is my code :----

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import os
import time
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('ticker_tape_links.csv')
results = []

start = time.time()

def get_tasks(session,start,end):
    tasks = []
    for url in data['links'][start:end]:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(session.get(url, ssl=False)))
    return tasks

async def get_symbols(start,end):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session,start,end)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for response in responses:
            results.append(response)

await get_symbols(0,1000)
end = time.time()
total_time = end - start
print("It took {} seconds to make {} API calls".format(total_time, len(data['links'][0:1000])))
```

I used `await get_symbols(0,1000)` instead of `asyncio.run(get_symbols())` because the latter is not supported in jupyter notebook but the former works

Comment: Are you being rate limited?

Comment: Not sure what is happening. it just never stops running if I run them one by one in a non synchronous way some times it shows to many request connection aborded I think issue is something similar but while using asyncio it is showing no such error it just runs forever

Comment: What is in your `ticker_tape_links.csv`? Also how are you using `await` outside an async function?